# Plural Singletons for class with generic parameters

Tags: scala, generics, singleton

Is it possible in Scala to define the singletons for a class with a generic parameter? Yes its the plural, because there must be a singleton for each instance of the generic parameter. This is nonsense in the most general case, I believe, but if the generic parameter is a subtype of something specific, I wonder whether it may work.

As an example consider as the specific supertype of all generic parameters to be this abstract class.

```
abstract class BaseType[T<:BaseType] {
  val omega:T;
}
```

The idea is that each implementation has a special value, and this is omega. Now I want a class which has subtypes of `BaseType` as a generic parameter:

```
class Thing[T<:BaseType[T]](val v:T, foo:Int);
```

Because each `T` has the specific value `omega`, I would like to have singletons for `Thing` containing `omega` and, say, `foo=0`. I cannot even do

```
object Thing {
  def OmegaInstance[T<:BaseType[T]] = new Thing(/*what gos here?*/, 0);
}
```

but even if I could, the OmegaInstance would be new for each call, which I don't want.

Any chance to get this working?

Comment: You definitely need instance of T<:BaseType[T] to pass in Thing constructor

Comment: Clearly that would be the Java way. Given all the nice type tricks, I wondered whether Scala can do a little miracle here.

Comment: in this case you should have some implicit that would provide T<:BaseType[T]

Answer (score 0):

If your input type parameter is not erased you can implement same old lightweight pattern, but with `TypeTag` as a key:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._ 
import scala.collection.concurrent._

object Things {
   class Thing[T] private[Things]() { //private constructor, class itself is still accessable
       //...
   }

   private val map = TrieMap[TypeTag[_], Thing[_]]()

   def Thing[T: TypeTag] = 
          map.getOrElseUpdate(typeTag[T], new Thing[T]).asInstanceOf[Thing[T]] //`asInstanceOf` is safe here

}
```

Usage examples:

```
import Things._

scala> Thing[Int]
res2: Things.Thing[Int] = Things$Thing@4472abe8 //new object

scala> Thing[Int]
res3: Things.Thing[Int] = Things$Thing@4472abe8 //same object

scala> Thing[Int]
res4: Things.Thing[Int] = Things$Thing@4472abe8 //same object

scala> Thing[String]
res5: Things.Thing[String] = Things$Thing@4745c8d2 //new object

scala> Thing[String]
res6: Things.Thing[String] = Things$Thing@4745c8d2 //same object
```

You can instantiate any thing you want with any parameter here. The usage looks almost like just having generic-parameterized `object` (one singleton for every generic).